# Shorter trigger keyword for Opensearch in omnibox

Tags: opensearch, omnibox

Is it possible to make a shorter keyword for the users to access our opensearch?

Example:
Our website is: xxxxxxxxx.com
I want that when typing 'xxx' and pressing TAB the opensearch for our website will appear.
Right now the users have to type the whole address and then press TAB.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to make keyword shorter, if you search is on xxxxxxxxx.com, keyword is xxxxxxxxx.com, you can't do with it anything.

Nevertheless you probably also don't have any problem.
Google Chrome behaviour is as follows:
User visits site with opensearch link. Google Chrome plug this search engine, and then when you start typing first x into location bar, xxx engine is offered with pressing TAB key.

You probably did something wrong, when you was testing it (and didn't post here infos about it).
Because when you add manually new search engine, you need first at least once visit site, engine belongs it. Otherwise you must type whole xxxxxx.com.